# Rule to send mail to the users about the percentage of their profile completed(single & multiple profiles)

Tags: rules, users

I am trying to write a rule to send an email to the user if his/her one of the profiles is not completed. But I am not getting how to get the empty field's list to sent to the user. What actually i wanted to do is. List all the fields which are empty from profile (Single & multiple) and sent the list to the user, requesting to fill all the details or just percentage of profile completion . Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Content Complete](https://drupal.org/project/content_complete) or [Profile Complete Percent](https://drupal.org/project/pcp) to track profile completion. Content Complete integrates with Rules.

Comment: As I am working on drupal 7 I am using profile2 and pcp modules. How to integrate pcp module with rules?